# How to swap strings from an 3d array of strings using pointers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I'm trying to sort alphabetically a matrix of strings using the next code:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<math.h>
#define Ld 2
#define Cd 2
#define Ds 20

void swap_char(char** a, char** b)
{
char *temp= *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}


int strCmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
int result;
while ( (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0') && (*s1 == *s2))
{
    s1++;
    s2++;
}

result = (*s1 == *s2) ? 0 : (*s1 > *s2) ? 1 : -1;

return result;
}

int main(void)
{
 char mat_char[2][2][20] = { "ana", "maria", "elena", "julia" };
 int i, j, k;
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        char* pmat_char = mat_char;
        printf("%s", (pmat_char + i * 2 * 20 + j * 20) );

        //getchar();
    }
    printf("\n");
}

getchar();
printf("\n");
printf("\n");

for (i = 0; i < Ld; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < Cd; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; mat_char[i][j][k] != '\0'; k++)
        {
            printf("%c", mat_char[i][j][k]);
        }
        
        printf("\t");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


for (i = 0; i < Cd*Ld; i++)
{
    char* pmat_char = mat_char;
    printf("%s\t", (pmat_char + i * 20));
    
}
printf("\n");


for (i = 0; i < ((Ld * Cd) - 1); ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < ((Ld * Cd) - 1 - i); ++j)
    {
        char* pmat_char = mat_char;
        char* str1 = pmat_char + j * 20;
        char* str2 = pmat_char + (j + 1) * 20;
        char* aux;
        if (strCmp(pmat_char + j*20, pmat_char + (j + 1)*20) > 0)
        {
            swap_char( &str1, &str2);
            printf("Dupa swap este %s \t %s", str1, str2);
            getchar();
            aux = pmat_char + j * 20;
            *(pmat_char + j * 20)= *str1;

            *(pmat_char + (j + 1) * 20) = *aux;

        }
        

    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
for (i = 0; i < Ld; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < Cd; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; mat_char[i][j][k] != '\0'; k++)
        {
            printf("%c", mat_char[i][j][k]);
        }

        printf("\t");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have to work more at the function StrCmp, but I want help in the swap function. I don't understand why after I call the swap function, the string in the matrix are not swaped.
I tried something with aux, but it's not ok yet. I have also a lot matrix printf because I wanted to understand how it's working this matrix.
I noticed that mat_char[0] includes the first 2 strings ("ana" and "maria") and mat_char[1] includes the next 2 strings ("elena", "julia"). The point that when I put  *(pmat_char + j * 20)= *str1; it change also *str2.

Comment: Use `strcpy` instead of swapping pointers.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Too slow, not necessary.

Comment: I want to practice and that's why I wrote also strcpy, but I have to modify there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I used Method 1 from there, swaping pointers

Comment: But it;s not swaping in mat_char

Comment: @RobertHarvey Since the array is declared as `char mat_char[2][2][20]` I would think `strcpy` is the only way to swap the strings in the array. Admittedly, the code is a little hard to follow so I may be missing something.

Comment: The swap function swaps the pointers of two strings, nothing more.  How it is used in-context (how it is called) is another matter entirely.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. (there are no pointers to swap!)

Comment: @RobertHarvey : no it is a character array (with an initialiser).

Comment: The simplest thing I can come up with that works: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/ExcitingAbleBit#main.c  It swaps pointers; it doesn't use `strcpy`.

Comment: Arrays are *not* pointers.  In many contexts, the name of an array decays to a  pointer to its first element, but arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: That's fine; check out the code I posted.

Comment: New link: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/Swap-Strings-in-a-Matrix

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah. I see. Your method only "works" because the string lengths are less than the size of a pointer and you are passing a `char *` as a `char **`. It won't work with longer strings. https://godbolt.org/z/Eoondrc4n

Comment: @JohnnyMopp:  Thanks for the explanation; that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: I think I managed to do it correctly: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/Swap-Strings-in-a-Matrix-by-Pointer

Comment: @RobertHarvey Unfortunately, you have changed the data type from `char matrix[dimX][dimY][stringLength]` to `char* matrix[dimX][dimY];` and that is a _major difference_. Your method is great for the latter datatype but is not correct for the former. The former is one block of memory with the chars of the strings inside. The latter is a block of pointers - each pointer points to a separate memory location outside the array.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: I don't think pointer swapping can be done with the former.  You'd have to use strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
char mat_char[2][2][20] = ...;
```

you defined a single block of contiguos memory of `2 * 2 * 20 = 80` chars. It's not a Matrix of string pointers, it's just 80 chars of memory.

So later when you do this:

```
    char* str1 = pmat_char + j * 20;
    char* str2 = pmat_char + (j + 1) * 20;
    ...
    swap_char( &str1, &str2);
```

what you are swapping are the addresses stored in `str1` and `str2`. It's the same as writing:

```
    char* str2 = pmat_char + j * 20;
    char* str1 = pmat_char + (j + 1) * 20;
```

Nothing has been swaped in the mat_char. Only thing that affects the mat_char is

```
        aux = pmat_char + j * 20;
        *(pmat_char + j * 20)= *str1;
        *(pmat_char + (j + 1) * 20) = *aux;
```

That copies a single char from `(pmat_char + (j + 1) * 20)` to `(pmat_char + j * 20)` overwriting the first char of the original string in the process.

My guess is that your strings likely start with the same char so you don't see any effect. But you are corrupting your strings here.

Further breaking your code you have this nice line a bit earlier:

```
    char* pmat_char = mat_char;

    warning: initialization of 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'char (*)[2][20]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Listen to your compiler. The whole compare and swap loop is UB.